# Java - Converting the characters in a string array depending on whether or not it's a vowel

Tags: java, string, character

The method takes in any name and tests whether a character is a vowel or consonant. If it's a vowel, it makes the character uppercase, if it's a consonant, it makes the character lowercase. Any thoughts? I don't know how to add `.toUpperCase` and `.toLowerCase` in the if else statements.

```
public static void parsing(String name[])
{
    String temp = name[0];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
    {
        if(temp.charAt(i) == 'a' || temp.charAt(i) == 'A' ||
           temp.charAt(i) == 'e' || temp.charAt(i) == 'E' ||
           temp.charAt(i) == 'i' || temp.charAt(i) == 'I' ||
           temp.charAt(i) == 'o' || temp.charAt(i) == 'O' ||
           temp.charAt(i) == 'u' || temp.charAt(i) == 'U')
        {
         System.out.print(temp.charAt(i).toUpperCase);
        }//Obviously wrong but I don't know what to do.
            else
            {
            System.out.print(temp.charAt(i).toLowerCase);
            }//Obviously wrong but I don't know what to do.     
    }
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this?

Comment: String.equalsIgnoreCase is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a single character use the methods from the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class:

```
System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(temp.charAt(i)));
System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(temp.charAt(i)));
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is much shorter than the other answers. Thanks, John.

Answer (score 1):

Create two final arrays - one with the vowels, the second one with the consonants. Then check, whether the current char in the loop is a vowel or consonant and make the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your are hitting your head as String is immutable. Rebuild the resulting string.
A (bit suboptimal) solution is:

```
public static void parsing(String[] names)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        names[i] = chAngEd(names[i]);
    }
}

private static String chAngEd(String s) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a' || ...) {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        } else {
            ch = ...
        }
        result += ch;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void parsing(String names[]){
   for (int i=0; i<names.length; ++i){
       names[i] = capitaliseConsts(names[i]);
   }
}


private static String capitaliseConsts(String name){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Character c;

    for (int i=0; i<name.length(); ++i){
        c = name.charAt(i);
        if (c.equalsIgnoreCase('a') || 
            c.equalsIgnoreCase('e') ||
            c.equalsIgnoreCase('i') ||
            c.equalsIgnoreCase('o') ||
            c.equalsIgnoreCase('u')){

          sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
       }
       else{
             sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
       }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String vowelsArray = "aeiuo";
String constantsArray = "uppercase constants";
int stringLength = name.length();
String givenNameCopy = name.ToString();
for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++){
if(vowelsArray.contains(givenNameCopy[i]))
   then uppercase
else if(constantsArray.contains(givenNameCopy[i]))
   then lowercase
else
    continue;
```

hope this helps.